# SQL Column Regex Restriction

Tags: sql, mariadb, xampp

I want to create a column in my table that have some restriction -->
CustomerID must starts with ‘CU’ and followed by 3 numbers (e.g. CU001, CU928, CU999, etc.)

just fyi, I use xampp

```
CREATE TABLE `MsCustomer`(
    CustomerID CHAR(5) CHECK (CustomerID LIKE '^CU\d{3}$'),
    CustomerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CustomerGender VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CustomerAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CustomerEmail VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CustomerDOB DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID)
)
```

```
INSERT INTO `mscustomer`(CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerGender, CustomerAddress, CustomerEmail, CustomerDOB)
VALUES ('CU001', 'Dirk Titterel', 'Male', '74 Melvin Point', 'Dtitterel0@yellowpages.com', 2003-10-29);
```

I tried '^CU\d{3}$' and 'CU[0-9][0-9][0-9]'

I don't know why it keep getting these error when I want to insert something, is it my regex is it my insert?

#4025 - CONSTRAINT `mscustomer.CustomerID` failed for `groceries`.`mscustomer`

Answer (score 1):

Solved: Use RLIKE instead of LIKE when using regex